# wallet password and balance

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I have been mining to the address I created on my mining Linux box with geth. I can list my accounts with `geth account list` but how do I check my balance. My mining pool has made one payout to my address since I've started mining so I should have .02 eth there but I'd like to see it to be sure. Secondly I'm not sure if I even remember my password or not and I don't know where or how to enter my password to verify if I remember it or not. How can I check my password with geth? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
geth attach

then

eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]);
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "you passWord",10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just checking your balance and you know your public address, you can do it 2 ways without exposing your private key;

#### Using a block explorer

Block explorers - like https://etherscan.io - are *usually* up-to-date on showing you block information, which also has your address balance.

#### Using `geth`

You don't need to expose your private key here either if you know your public key. You can run the following in your geth console

```
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('<<your_address>>'),'ether').toString(10)
```

(Make sure your geth instance is in sync with the latest block (`eth.getBlock("latest").number`) otherwise it'll (possibly) show the wrong amount depending on how far out of sync it is)

#### Remember your password!

Hopefully you can remember your password or have access to your private key so you can then sign and broadcast transactions with the address using geth or a gui like https://myetherwallet.com